# SPFx - Cannot find type definition file for 'es6-collections'

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to create a solution which will deploy the assets to SP online by following [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package). Since this is based on version 1.4.0 i have udpated 
@microsoft-* packages to 1.4.0
But I am getting following error. I am  not understanding how to make this packages sync.

```
Cannot find type definition file for 'es6-collections'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a known issue while upgrading from SPFx 1.3 to 1.4

To fix it, just install the typed definitions of es6-collections as below:

```
npm install --save @types/es6-collections
```

Comment: This is great. One quick question, how I can check the version of typescript installed in my machine?

Comment: Not really 100% sure, but if i open VS Code, its displayed at the bottom bar like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7tgz.png).
If it helped resolve your isse, can you please mark it answer :)

Comment: Seems image is wrong. I am asking similar command as `npm --version`

Comment: Currently spfx 1.4 uses Typescript 2.4.2

Comment: If typescript is installed globally, you can try `npm -list -g --depth=0`

Answer (score 2):

Please update your tsconfig.json (in the root of the project). The latest yeoman generator creates it like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@microsoft"
    ],
    "types": [
      "es6-promise",
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es5",
      "dom",
      "es2015.collection"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: what should we update tsconfig.json to ?  What changes do we need to make ?

Comment: you should add es6 to lib section at the top